# how to make multiple api calls node.js promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to promises and async programming in javascript, and I'm trying to make multiple API calls to google maps places API in node.js then send data to the client once all the data is received. However, I'm getting some kind of a syntax error saying missing ) after argument list. Sorry if I'm asking a stupid question, I just can't seem to figure the issue out. Thanks for the help!

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = (app) => {

    app.post('/search-champ', (req, res) => {


        console.log(req);
        let lat = req.body.param.lat; //before: req.query.lat it's wrong

        let long = req.body.param.long;
        console.log(lat);

        const apiId = 'AIzaSyAeEPop5mofzDJhytOEMtxXaGWFqGB4Q3M';
        const urls = [

            'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=' + lat + ',' + long + '&rankby=distance&type=department_store&key=AIzaSyAeEPop5mofzDJhytOEMtxXaGWFqGB4Q3M',

            'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=' + lat + ',' + long + '&rankby=distance&type=food&key=AIzaSyAeEPop5mofzDJhytOEMtxXaGWFqGB4Q3M'
        ];


        Promise.all(urls.map(url =>


            fetch(url)
            .then(checkStatus)


            .then(data => {

                console.log(data)
                res.send({
                    data

                });
            })

        }).catch(err => {
            res.redirect('/error');
        });

        function checkStatus(response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                return Promise.resolve(response);
            } else {
                return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText));
            }
        }




    })
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a curly brace on this line (at the end): `Promise.all(urls.map(url =>`

Comment: You have `}).catch(err => {` but you need `)).catch(err => {`  -  - Also, instead of `res.send(data)` you need `return data;`, then actually finish your `Promise.all()` by putting a `.then( ... )` before `.catch( ... )`.

Comment: You also need to insert `.then(r => r.json())` after the `fetch()`  btw.

Comment: @ronald shirman i'll suggest you to make your code as much cleaner as much you can, it will help you in identification of any unwanted syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Fetch in javascript return an response promise object you have to call the json method on it. Change your `checkStatus` method to this.

```
function checkStatus(response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                return Promise.resolve(response.json());
            } else {
                return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText));
            }
        }
```

Comment: 1. you have to do this before checking `response.ok` I assume 2. OP is using `node-fetch`, an npm package, but it happens to work the same way

Comment: @ChrisG Why there is a need to check before response.ok. Instead of returning the promise object (Promise.resolve and Promise.reject ) we can directly return the values `function checkStatus(response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                return new Error(response.statusText);
            }
        }`

Comment: You're right, `.ok` is part of the `Response` returned by `fetch`. I thought it's a custom field by the OP that's only available in the actual response data.

Answer (score 0):

The `res.send({ data });` is called for every url in the array, this is probably not what you want, to wait for all api calls to complete, place the `res.send()` in the `then()` of the `Promise.all()`

```
Promise.all(urls.map(url =>
  fetch(url)
  .then(checkStatus)
).then(data => {
  console.log(data)
  res.send({ data });
}).catch(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
module.exports = (app) => {
    app.post('/search-champ', (req, res) => {
        let lat = req.body.param.lat; //before: req.query.lat it's wrong
        let long = req.body.param.long;
        const apiId = 'AIzaSyAeEPop5mofzDJhytOEMtxXaGWFqGB4Q3M';
        const urls = [
            'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=' + lat + ',' + long + '&rankby=distance&type=department_store&key=AIzaSyAeEPop5mofzDJhytOEMtxXaGWFqGB4Q3M',
            'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=' + lat + ',' + long + '&rankby=distance&type=food&key=AIzaSyAeEPop5mofzDJhytOEMtxXaGWFqGB4Q3M'
        ];
        var apiData = urls.map( (url) => {
            return fetch(url).then(checkStatus);
        });
        Promise.all(apiData)
            .then( (data) => {
            res.send({
                data: data
            });
        });

        function checkStatus(response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                return Promise.resolve(response);
            } else {
                return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText));
            }
        }
    });
}
```